# React.js Styled Components : Adding HTML attributes

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

So we are using `styled-components`. I want to do some work on our accessibility and need to add `tabindex="0"` as HTML attribute to some of those components. How do i do this without it being passed as a prop?

e.g.

`<PlayButton className={className} onClick={handleClick} tabindex="0">`

Comment: Why don't you want to pass it as a prop?

Comment: @ksav i did not realize i could camelCase it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using the attribute spread operator:

```
let props = condition ? {tabIndex: 1} : {};
let div = <div {...props} />
```

or you can check out their documentation [Guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html)

Example:

React has always provided a JavaScript-centric API to the DOM. Since React components often take both custom and DOM-related props, React uses the camelCase convention just like the DOM APIs:

```
<div tabIndex="-1" />      // Just like node.tabIndex DOM API
<div className="Button" /> // Just like node.className DOM API
<input readOnly={true} />  // Just like node.readOnly DOM API
```

These props work similarly to the corresponding HTML attributes, with the exception of the special cases documented above.

Answer (score 6):

You can add tabIndex straight to the styled component it just has to be camelCase:

`<PlayButton className={className} onClick={handleClick} tabIndex="0" />`

in react docs:
https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html